sf project deploy succeeds but LWC is not updated in scratch org
I am using sf project deploy start to deploy changes in my scratch org on a Lightning Web Component. The command works correctly: it tracks the changes in the components correctly, succeeds and shows a correct output too.
The changes don't appear in my scratch org though.
I tried using Debug mode, I tried refreshing, I clear the browser cache every time, I tried uninstalling my package just in case it interferes, but nothing. I end up always creating a new package version and clean-install it in my org as a workaround to view the changes, but I'm sure there's a quicker way around this, isn't it?

I don't understand why my question gets downvoted, can someone explain please? Am I asking something too obvious?

I figured it out, this response here helped me.
I had to assign to my user the permission set that my deployments have been creating. When I install the 2gen package in my orgs this step is not necessary, so it didn't cross my mind.
However, when I use the sf project deploy commands, a new set of all the objects/permission sets/LWCs/etc is "duplicated" in a sense (once created with my package, once with the deployment).
When I assign the permission set to my user I see the new set of LWCs I was looking for, and these indeed get updated with every sf project deploy command.

you should try to avoid installing the package and pushing your code to the same org. Use one scratch org for development.
You will make your life easier if you use one scratch org for development and where you push your code using  sf project deploy start .... for. And I highly recommend you create a little bash/powershell script to automate the creation of of the scratch org AND the assignment to the various permission sets that are required for you to "get up and started" in the org.
Then Use another scratch org for verifying your deployment process. Package => install => check.
That will make things easier in the long run and avoid you not being sure which version is which (was it deployed or was it installed?... even though when you push a change manually via deploy I think the class no longer shows as installed via package)/

Thank you for the feedback! That sounds like a good approach indeed.
